# How do I cross-compile a static linked MIPS build of oath-toolkit?

Tags: gcc, mips, cross-compiling, toolchain, buildroot

I am trying to build [OATH Toolkit](https://github.com/malept/oath-toolkit.git) for MIPS on an x86 system. I want to produce a static build so it would most likely work on any MIPS system.

Just to be more precise the supported ISA on target system are: `mips1 mips2 mips32r1 mips32r2`

From what I understood I need to prepare a toolchain in order to do this and I successfully configured and build [buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) so now I do have it inside `~/buildroot-2016.08.1/output/target`

How am I supposed to use/activate the buildroot in order to build the check put `oath-toolkit` code?

Note: I am not forced to use buildroot, so I would consider any alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

Just run the `configure` script with the appropriate arguments to use the Buildroot compiler as a cross-compiler, and with the argument to link statically.

```
./configure --enable-static --disable-shared \
     --target=mips-buildroot-linux-gnu --host=mips-buildroot-linux-gnu \
     CC=$HOME/buildroot-2016.08.1/output/host/usr/bin/mips-linux-gcc
```

The above is assuming you are using glibc and big-endian MIPS. Check the directory name of `~/buildroot-2016.08.1/output/host/usr/mips*` for the correct value of the `--target`/`--host` options, and the contents of `~/buildroot-2016.08.1/output/host/usr/bin` for the correct value of the `CC=` option.

Note that you have to choose the "*mips 32*" architecture variant (`BR2_mips_32`) to be compatible with all your target systems.

Note also that with glibc, you might not have a completely statically linked executable, because it will try to load the NSS libraries dynamically. This is the case e.g. if `getaddrinfo` is used to resolve a hostname. You need to use uClibc or musl to avoid that.